# No error , no output and data is not inserted in database in jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I am creating a registration form in JSP, I have coded the code and when deploy it on server then No error , no output and data is not inserted in database. Can any one solve the my problem.
What is uses Server: Tomcat 8, IDE: Eclipse Luna, Database: Oracle 12c.

index.jsp

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="process.jsp" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="uname" value="Name..." onclick="this.value" /><br>
    <input type="text" name="uemail" value="Email..." onclick="this.value" /><br>
    <input type="password" name="upass" value="Password..."
        onclick="this.value" /><br> <input type="submit"
        value="Register">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

process.jsp

```
<%@ page import="registration.RegisterDao"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="registration.User"></jsp:useBean>
<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj" />
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<%
    int status = RegisterDao.register(obj);
    if (status > 0)
        out.print("You are successfully registered");
%>

</body>
</html>
```

user.java

```
package registration;

public class User {

private String uname;
private String upass;
private String uemail;

public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}

public String getUpass() {
    return upass;
}

public void setUpass(String upass) {
    this.upass = upass;
}

public String getUemail() {
    return uemail;
}

public void setUemail(String uemail) {
    this.uemail = uemail;
}
```

}

provider.java

```
 package registration;

public interface Provider {

String DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle12c";

String USERNAME = "AtulRai";
String PASSWORD = "atulrai";
```

}

connectionProvider.java

```
 package registration;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import static registration.Provider.*;

public class ConnectionProvider {

private static Connection con = null;

static {

    try {

        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, USERNAME,
                PASSWORD);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getCon() {
    return con;
}
```

}

Registerdao.java

```
 package registration;

 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class RegisterDao {

public static int register(User u) {
    int status = 0;

    try {

        Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

        PreparedStatement ps = con
                .prepareStatement("insert into detail values(?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, u.getUname());
        ps.setString(2, u.getUemail());
        ps.setString(3, u.getUpass());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

Other details are: my table name is DETAIL and column name is NAME, EMAIL, PASS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are missing  executeUpdate() statement in your register() inside DAO class :**

*This method Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statement, such as INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.*
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

```
  public static int register(User u) {
  int status = 0;

    try {

    Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();

    PreparedStatement ps = con
            .prepareStatement("insert into detail values(?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, u.getUname());
    ps.setString(2, u.getUemail());
    ps.setString(3, u.getUpass());

   status = ps.executeUpdate();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
   return status;
}
```

Comment: I have modified it with ps.executeUpdate() and when run it the url show only http://localhost:8080/JSPLearning/RegistrationForm/process.jsp?uname=Atul&uemail=atul@gmail.com&upass=raiatul and nothing else...??

Comment: @RealSkeptic: there is no output also. Wuould u please tell me what i change in "status"  ???

Comment: can you log (or sysout) value of status and check what is the value ?

Comment: I have checked my database. now i am able to insert the value but no output on the browser thats  means @process.jsp is not executed.

Comment: @GuruJi did you add the change VA31 suggested for the status?

Comment: I am new/fresher guy sir, I am not able to understand and unable to think what to change in status? If you tell me the process then I will able to change it and very thankfull of u sir...

Comment: @VA31: I have seen the above code. Now all is working. Thank u so much sir.

Comment: I just spent 2 hours trying to solve the exact same problem (to be honest, it's not really a problem, just a stupid omission on our part). I even thought of changing mysql configurations. How silly. Thank you!